# How to know when application stops ignoring my clicks c#

Tags: c#, click, window, handle

I'm clicking on an external application. It works fine. However, if I click an specific drawn button it takes some time to process and until it finishes, my future clicks are ignored (even though spy++ shows them).

I want to click on this second drawn button as soon as I know it can be clicked and the first button processed the click as well.

How can I know when this application will stop ignoring my future clicks and actually process them?

I tried using `SendMessageTimeout` without success because it says the external application is processing messages. It may process them (maybe) but they are being ignored. Is there anything I can do?

Some code:

```
private void checkIfItsAvailable(IntPtr handle)
    {

        uint timeout = 1;
        UIntPtr a;
        IntPtr lResult = SendMessageTimeout(
            handle,
            0,
            UIntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            0x0008,
            timeout,
            out a);
    }
```

Clicking, which works, and as there is no handle, on a specific point:

```
        public static void ClickHandlePoint(IntPtr handle, Point pt)
    {
        EnableWindow(handle, true);
        PostMessage(handle, 0x201, 1, MakeLParam(pt.X, pt.Y));
        PostMessage(handle, 0x202, 1, MakeLParam(pt.X, pt.Y));
    }
```

Comment: since it is an external application you don't have acess to any code right ?

Comment: Correct. It's an external application where buttons are actually drawn so I can't get a handle nor an Automation element

Comment: you could try to use an tracer and when you see that the process is done with your first click proceed with the second action .  It is probably overkill but since you are stuck and no one else comes up with a solution it is the best i can provide.   So you start to trace the external application when the first click is sent. You can then analyse the trace of the application and detect when he seems "ready" and input your second click.   I can't really provide code/exemple i only used tracer to debug my application. Hope it could help :)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look how to do it. Any idea what functions or similar shall I look for? I didn't know I could do that for an external application, thought tracing is only done in your own application

Comment: Hi. Using polling it wasn't working. However, I used threads and it worked, at least from 10ms.